# Append data from TDMS file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a folder TDMS files (can also be Excel).
These are stored in 5 MB packages, but all contain the same data structure.
Unfortunately there is no absolute time in the lines and the timestamp is stored somewhat cryptically in the column "TimeStamp" in the following format

"Tues. 17.11.2020 19:20:15"

But now I would like to load each file and plot them one after the other in the same graph.
For one file this is no problem, because I simply use the index of the file for the x-axis, but if I load several files, the index in each file is the same and the data overlap.

Does anyone have an idea how I can write all the data into a DataFrame, but with a continuous timestamp, so that the data can be plotted one after the other or I can also specify a time period in which I would like to see the data?

My first approach would be as follows.
If someone could upload an example with a CSV file (pandas.read.csv) instead of npTDMS Module, it would be just as helpful!

https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from nptdms import TdmsFile



tdms_file = TdmsFile.read("Datei1.tdms")
tdms_groups = tdms_file.groups()
tdms_Variables_1 = tdms_file.group_channels(tdms_groups[0])

MessageData_channel_1 = tdms_file.object('Data', 'Position')
MessageData_data_1 = MessageData_channel_1.data
    
#MessageData_channel_2 = tdms_file.object('Data', 'Timestamp')
#MessageData_data_2 = MessageData_channel_2.data

df_y = pd.DataFrame(data=MessageData_data_1).append(df_y)
    
plt.plot(df_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with CSV. It will first create a bunch of files that should look similar to yours in the `./data/` folder. Then it will read those files back (finding them with `glob`). It uses `pandas.concat` to combine the dataframes into 1, and then it parses the date.

```py
import glob
import random
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a bunch of test files that look like your data (NOTE: my files aren't 5MB, but 100 rows)
df = pandas.DataFrame([{"value": random.randint(50, 100)} for _ in range(1000)])
df["timestamp"] = pandas.date_range(
    start="17/11/2020", periods=1000, freq="H"
).strftime(r"%a. %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
chunks = [df.iloc[i : i + 100] for i in range(0, len(df) - 100 + 1, 100)]
for index, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk[["timestamp", "value"]].to_csv(f"./data/data_{index}.csv", index=False)

# ===============

# Read the files back into a dataframe
dataframe_list = []
for file in glob.glob("./data/data_*.csv"):
    df = pandas.read_csv(file)
    dataframe_list.append(df)

# Combine all individual dataframes into 1
df = pandas.concat(dataframe_list)

# Set the time file correctly
df["timestamp"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format=r"%a. %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

# Use the timestamp as the index for the dataframe, and make sure it's sorted
df = df.set_index("timestamp").sort_index()

# Create the plot
plt.plot(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gijs Wobben

Thank you so much ! It works perfectly well and it will save me a lot of work !
As a mechanical engineer you don't write code like this very often, so I'm happy if people from other disciplines can help you.

Here is the basic structure, how i did it directly with TDMS-Files, because I read afterwards that the npTDMS module offers the possibility to read the data directly as dataframe, which I didn't know before

```
import pandas as pd
from nptdms import TdmsFile
from nptdms import tdms
import os,glob


file_names=glob.glob('*.tdms')
    
tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(file_names[0])

# Read the files back into a dataframe
dataframe_list = []
for file in glob.glob("*.tdms"):
    tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(file)
    df = tdms_file['Sheet1'].as_dataframe()
    dataframe_list.append(df)
    
df_all = pd.concat(dataframe_list)    

# Set the time file correctly
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format=r"%a. %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

# Use the timestamp as the index for the dataframe, and make sure it's sorted
df = df.set_index("Timestamp").sort_index()

# Create the plot
plt.plot(df)
```